# Flutter_tex generate list of TeXViewDocuments dynamically

Tags: flutter, latex, formula, flutter-tex

so for example I have a list of Strings in Latex like:

```
List<String> example = [
    LatexString1,
    LatexString2,
    LatexString3,
    LatexString4
  ];
```

But this list is created dynamically case by case, so I don't know, how long the list will be (and what the content of the list will be).

What I want now is a created list of that LatexStrings on the smartphone with Flutter_tex, but I really don't know how to do it. Is it even possible? Cause normally for cases like that I use `List.View.seperated` widget with an `itemBuilder` which works pretty well for non latex-Strings.

 So also I can not put a `List.View` Widget into a `TexView` Widget.

Perhaps for a better imagination: I want a list like the "Hallo"s in the picture just with Math Formulas given by Latex :)

[image]

So if someone could help me with that problem, that would be really really nice.

Thanks a lot and kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `TeXViewGroup`. It has a `children` property that you can set by using the `map` method on `example`. So, it would look something like:

```dart
TeXView(
    child: TeXViewGroup(
       children: example.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
           return TeXViewGroupItem(
               id: entry.key.toString(), 
               child: TeXViewDocument(entry.value)
           );
       }).toList().cast<TeXViewGroupItem>(),
       onTap: ((id){})
    )
)
```

You might need to edit that snippet as per your needs, but here is the official usage example: [See from line 125](https://github.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex/blob/master/example/lib/tex_view_quiz_example.dart)

In the example, the `map` is directly used because the list items already have unique values (every child of the `TeXViewGroup` widget must have a unique id), but since your's doesn't, you'll need to use `.asMap().entries` and later type caste it as shown in the above snippet.